# webpack 4 multiple sets of entries with code-splitting unique to each

Tags: javascript, optimization, webpack, webpack-4, code-splitting

Lets say there is an app with multiple server-generated pages, each with an old backbone "single page app". For instance, Settings (/settings) is its own SPA. Foo is its own (/foo). Same with Bar, Qux, and Fox at their own urls. They don't interact with each other, but I'd like code-splitting so each SPA's bundle isn't bloated with the exact same third party deps.

The Webpack config might look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        settings: './js/settings.js',
        foo: './js/foo.js',
        bar: './js/bar.js',
        qux: './js/qux.js',
        fox: './js/fox.js'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    minChunks: 2,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
    },
}
```

But.. Now I want to add a new cool SPA, "Hot" at /hot using some hot different framework, lets say React. I don't want to share the same "vendors" bundle, though, since - as you can imagine - those five old SPA's have a very large dependency graph with almost none of the same deps as Hot, and I don't want Hot to have to pull down that bloat. If I add a property to `entry` like `hot: './js/hot.js'`, and previously just 1 of the old bundles was using d3, and now my Hot bundle does as well, d3 will be code-split into the vendors bundle. But this is what I don't want. Further, if later I add AlsoHot with many of the same deps as Hot, now these two will be pulled out into vendor?

Do I need two completely separate webpack configs to accomplish separate code-split bundles (without having to explicitly say which deps should go in each)? Basically what I think I want is something like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [{
        settings: './js/settings.js',
        foo: './js/foo.js',
        bar: './js/bar.js',
        qux: './js/qux.js',
        fox: './js/fox.js'
    }, {
        hot: './js/hot.js',
        alsoHot: './js/alsoHot.js'
    }],
    // rest is the same
}
```